# MooTools - Prevent events while other events are running

Tags: javascript, mootools

I've been trying to create a slide show, here is my attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/paulmason411/fNfKk/

It's working quite well, although if you click the continue or previous button really quick the slides don't line up.

Can I disable the next click listener while the tween is in progress?

any help would be great,
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not very veratile code, why don't you write a class? seems messy to deal with your variables this way.

anyway, several ways to tackle this.

easiest to make it work with your code without refactoring:
http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/fNfKk/2/

the idea is to have a scoped variable `moving` which gets set through the tween's `onStart` and `onComplete` events. the left/right slides then check if moving and if so, return w/o doing anything.

way 2: 
don't tween between 'current position, current position + width' as that is what causes your issues at the moment - if you click it midway, it will lose 'frame' er... focus (i.e. frames won't be centered)

instead, calculate how much each step is and keep a global scrollto var - then each previous/next should up/reduce the scrolltoval and fire a tween to it, eg `el.tween("left", scrollto);`. combine that with `link: 'cancel'` on the tween options and you can get fast-forward for the impatient.

good luck.

Comment: Thanks Dimitar, I was trying a similar method to your first solution. Although I wasn't setting the move variable in the onStart function. Makes sense now. I thought that MooTools would have it's own function for dealing with concurrent events, but this works so no need.

Can you tell me about link: 'cancel' I haven't used it and don't understand it's functionality. Thanks.

Comment: no worries. `link: "chain"` or `"cancel"` indicates how the new fx tween gets stacked up. when you have an ongoing effect and apply a new one, eg mouseenter/mouseleave animations, it can either: finish up old animation and then start the new one (chain) or cancel existing and start new one. look at the two ul groups here: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/9Ycgr/ top one will chain so mousenter will go all the way and then out on quick mouseovers/out whereas bottom one will start going back to 0 on mouseout straight away via cancel.